# Where does one place Models in a Laravel Package?

Tags: laravel, directory-structure

I'm currently following the [Laravel Package](http://laravel.com/docs/packages) documentation, which uses the `workbench` tool to create a standard package tree consisting of `controller`, `config`, `views`, etc. folders. Basically, most folders you would get in a standard Laravel app tree.

However, I had a couple of questions:

- Why is the `models` folder absent here? (though the same goes for `tests` and `commands`)
- Should I just create the folder myself and add it to the composer.json autoload classmap?
- What classes should live inside `src/<Namespace>/<PackageName>`? I have noticed that a ServiceProvider is automatically created here, but I can imagine most other files just existing in the standard package directories.

Answer (score 0):

Wockbench represents just a tool for creating other tools, that is triggered through CLI. Workbench is very abstract concept.

Model folder is absent simply because you don't need model in every new package. For example, if you are creating middleware package or you own filter package.

Every new class can be added to package dependent on its purpose and responsibility. It can be done in more then one way.

Classes that are general enough to go into every package are:

```
Package Service Provider
Facade
Basic Class
```

But it is not a black box. Consider for example request class - it is bound very early in the application life cycle, so no provider is needed.

Comment: But similarly you don't need controller in every package. Nor views. So why are those present and models not?

Comment: You are right, it may be just a matter of Laravel creator personal choice. Workbench is just a starting point. Of course that you will create classes that are specific to you package. Or link to other paths.I like to think about workbench like a bootstrap  for creating other things, so it is very abstract and opened.

Comment: I think Taylor's general idea is that a model is too constraining an idea. Controllers are required to do what controllers do, but most other classes are more abstract in how they deal with your app's business logic. It can certainly be argued that anything that extends `Eloquent\Model` is a very specific thing and therefore why not have a folder set up, similarly a base install of Laravel even provides a `models` directory so why not a package? You'd have to ask Taylor. But if you read his book you'll find him telling you to delete your app's `models` directory before you start coding.